# how can i fix this error=Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index"

Tags: vb.net

I have a gridview when i click the column  of the dataGridview the problem show
"error=Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index""

how can i fix this? please help
this is the whole code.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'construct dataGridview
    DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 4
    DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name = "name"
    DataGridView1.Columns(1).Name = "position"
    DataGridView1.Columns(2).Name = "team"
    DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullColumnSelect
End Sub
Private Sub Populate(name As String, pos As String, team As String)
    Dim row As String() = New String() {name, pos, team}
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
End Sub
Private Sub Retrieve()
    DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM peopleTB"
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)

    Try
        con.Open()
        adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        adapter.fill(dt)
        'fill dgview
        For Each row In dt.Rows
            Populate(row(1), row(2), row(3))
        Next
        con.Close()
        dt.Rows.Clear()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        con.Close()

    End Try

End Sub
Private Sub Cleartxt()
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    TextBox3.Text = ""
End Sub
'update db and dg
Private Sub UpdateDG(name As String)

    Dim sql As String = "UPDATE peopleTB Set N ='" + TextBox1.Text + "',P='" + TextBox2.Text + "',T='" + TextBox3.Text + "'WHERE N= '" + name + "'"
    'OPEN CON
    Try
        con.Open()
        adapter.updateCommand = con.CreateCommand()
        adapter.updateCommand.commandtext = sql

        If adapter.updateCommand.executenonquery() > 0 Then
            MsgBox("Success updated")
            Cleartxt()
        End If
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        con.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub DataGridView1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.MouseClick
    Dim name As String = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value
    Dim position As String = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value
    Dim team As String = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(2).Value
    TextBox1.Text = name
    TextBox2.Text = position
    TextBox3.Text = team
End Sub
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim name As String = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value
    UpdateDG(name)
End Sub
```

Im using ms access

Comment: If you get an error message telling you that you're using am invalid index then you need to use a valid index instead. You need to actually do some debugging, i.e. breakpoints and stepping through code. Work out what index you're using, what the valid range is, what index you should be using and then change the code accordingly.

Comment: What you should keep in mind is that collections in .NET have zero based indexes, meaning that the 1st element of something indexable has an index of 0 and the last one is (Count - 1). So debug as @jmcilhinney suggested and ensure that where you're expecting the 4th column for instance, you give it an index of 3. Ensure your loops go to Count - 1 and not up to count. I suspect this line `Populate(row(1), row(2), row(3))`, subtract 1 from each index if you wanted to populate the 1st through the 3rd columns in the row.